# Android: searchview history not showing

Tags: android, history, searchview

Im trying to get a searchview to show previously entered searches when a user starts typing.

Ive followed all of the instructions here at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html and looked around at various other places but I cant seem to get it working.

I'm using a searchview for a fragment in my app that allows users to look up the bus schedule for a particular stop. Code is below.

**transit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="Search"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          app:showAsAction="always"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
          android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.teamzeta.sfu.utilities.BusSuggestionProvider"
          android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"/>
</menu>
```

**BusSuggestionProvider**

```
package com.teamzeta.sfu.utilities;

import android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider;

public class BusSuggestionProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider{
    public final static String AUTHORITY = "com.teamzeta.sfu.utilities.BusSuggestionProvider";
    public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;

    public BusSuggestionProvider() {
        setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
    }
}
```

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/stop_number"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.teamzeta.sfu.utilities.BusSuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?">
</searchable>
```

**NextBusFragment onCreateOptionsMenu**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.transit, menu);
        MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search); 
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchViewItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.stop_number));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                search(s);
                SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(getActivity(), BusSuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, BusSuggestionProvider.MODE);
                suggestions.saveRecentQuery(s, null);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

**Manifest Provider**

```
 <provider android:name="com.teamzeta.sfu.utilities.BusSuggestionProvider"
               android:authorities="com.teamzeta.sfu.utilities.BusSuggestionProvider" />
 <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
```

The `search()` method goes off and retrieves the bus list from an API and then displays it on the screen in a listview.

Can anyone figure out why this isnt showing history?

Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you debug in `onQueryTextSubmit`? Is s' value proper?

Comment: The value submitted is good.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue in 2020

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your activity as "searchable" in your manifest:

```
<activity>
...
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```